# How do point to and import files into python script with databricks

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, databricks

My company recently moved to databricks. I used to have a python based pipeline that I ran off my local machine to quickly sort through and reformat our data files. The data is now being moved to a container on DataBricks. I would like to point to the container (which will be updated on a regular basis) and run my pipeline to reformat the data. However, I am facing a lot of trouble simplying trying to read in the data.

I first tried this (based off tutorials I found earlier)

```
import pyspark
import pandas as pd

storage_account_name = ''
storage_account_access_key =  ''
filename

spark.conf.set('fs.azure.account.key.' + storage_account_name + '.blob.core.windows.net', storage_account_access_key)
df = spark.read.format("xls").load(filename)
```

this gave me sclassNotFoundExceptionError.
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o3368.load. : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.crealytics.spark.excel.

I also tried reading it directly into Pandas but have not been able to figure out how to do that either.

I was hoping to import the file into a dataframe that I could then manipulate with pandas

Comment: Maybe add code that proves that file exists and is found? something like `os.path.isfile(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the Spark Excel library to your cluster so it registers the corresponding data source. Just follow the [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/en/libraries/cluster-libraries.html) on how to do that, and make sure that you selected a library with the correct Scala version (2.12) and Spark version (if there are different builds for different Spark versions). Also, there could be differences if you use Unity Catalog shared clusters vs. other cluster types.